# How can I send a copy of a receipt to member who has already recieved it during signup?

Tags: email, contributions

I've got a situation where by the template for the receipts (for contributions) which are sent out during signup had the previous year on it, and consequently, need to re-send the receipt to the members who have signed up in this year with an updated year.

I was wondering if there is any easy way to do this?, i can easily create a mailinglist, but i've no way of replicating the receipt (or just re-sending the currently sent ones, but with the new date) that I am aware of?

Answer (score 6):

Via **Contributions > Find Contributions** (`civicrm/contribute/search`) you can search for the contributions in question, then select *Print or Email Contribution Receipts*.

The next page is titled *Print Contribution Receipts* but it has an option to email them anyway.